# How to determine which submit type button calls a servlet

Tags: html, servlets

I have a form with a table inside. There are buttons in every row which are submit type and every one of them calls a servlet.
Every button has a different name attribute but the label on the buttons is the same.

Inside the called servlet I would like to determine which one of the buttons was pressed and called that servlet.

```
<form method='POST' action='/Assignment/DateRequestServlet' name='daterequestform'>
    <table padding = '5' border = '1'>
            <tr>
               <td>
                   <button name='button1' type='submit'> Request Date</button>
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>
                   <button name='button2' type='submit'> Request Date</button>
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>
                   <button name='button3' type='submit'> Request Date</button>
               </td>
            </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

In the servlet i have tried req.getAttribute("name") or req.getParameter("name") but they both return a null.

I would like to do something that will return the name of the button, i.e.: button1, button2 or button3 in this example.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Kind regards

Lukasz

Answer (score 0):

Include a "value" in your button:

```
<button name='button1' type='submit' value='first_one'> Request Date</button>

<button name='button2' type='submit' value='second_one'> Request Date</button>
```

and so on.  You'll be able to get this value in your servlet on a per button basis.

See also the [W3Schools reference](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_value.asp).

**EDIT:**
I've included some code that works for me:

*HTML*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Button Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method='POST' action='/buttonHandler' name='daterequestform'>
    <table padding = '5' border = '1'>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <button name='button' type='submit' value="button1"> Request Date</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <button name='button' type='submit' value="button2"> Request Date</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <button name='button' type='submit' value="button3"> Request Date</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

*Java*

```
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/buttonHandler")
public class ButtonHandler extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        System.out.println( "you pushed button " + request.getParameter("button"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that! now when I'm on the servlet side and do req.getParameter("button1") it returns Request Date which is the label on the button, instead of the value assigned to the button. Any ideas?

Comment: Instead of using button tag, just try using the following tag    <input type='submit' name='button1' value='first_one'> Request Date</button>

<input type='submit'  name='button2' value='second_one'> Request Date</button>

Comment: And also what is the browser you are using ?